# Which PHP extensions do most web hosts commonly have installed and enabled?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, php, shared-hosting

I'm building a WordPress plugin intended for wide release, and would like to be able to rely on the `openssl` and `gmp` extensions, which require that PHP was compiled with those extensions specified and that they're enabled in `php.ini`. I know I can check if the extensions are loaded and throw an error if not, and I know that savvy users can manually enable an extension and non-savvy-but-motivated users could ask their web host to enable them, but I'd like maximum compatibility out of the gate.

I know it won't be 100% of hosts, but I'd be happy with 90% or even "yes most of them", but I can't find any way to get a sense of what extensions are commonly available. All I know is that my HostGator site and my Pantheon site both have `openssl` and `gmp` enabled, but that the default php7 install on arch linux has `openssl` but not `gmp`.

According to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42212/41534 and https://github.com/johnbillion/ext, `openssl` is required by WordPress only for `PHPMailer`, and `gmp` is not required, so it seems likely but not certain that hosts that support WordPress will enable `openssl`, but don't know about `gmp`. WordPress does require PHP version 7.3 or greater so I'm assuming that at least.

But beyond these two particular extensions it would be great to have some way to get a sense generically of what's commonly enabled, even though there won't be a perfect answer.